# How to save some information of our data at the current time for the future?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Due to limited data for some of the timeframes we cannot see long past time.
For example I cannot see the candles in 1m timeframe for 2 years ago.
Now I am wondering if there is a way that when I am currently running my pinescript, be able to save this information somewhere and show them in the chart when I am in 4H time frame and this information be saved for my future time as far as 4H is still available.

I know it is confusing, so I am trying to reword it.

Lets say, my code is using both 4H and 1min, is there a way that for the current time that both 1min and 4H are available the code does its job and save it somehow and I be able to see those stuff 1 month from now? the issue is that 1 month from now the 4H of the 1 month ago still exists but the 1min of 1 month ago does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Your script will run on each bar that is available on your chart and that's it.

The number of historical bars you have depends on your subscription type.

[image]